# Make sure geometry_msgs::Twist or cmd_vel units

Tags: navigation, kobuki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I have confusion about the unit of geometry_msgs::Twist, are they m/s and rad/s? Because I saw the sample code turltebot teleop as well as kobuki teleop, they setup these parameters equal 1.0 for each press button. However I checked the specification of the turtlebot kobuki in this [link](http://kobuki.yujinrobot.com/home-en/about/specifications/) , the maximum of linear velocity is just 70 cm/s, if my above opinion is right, the setup parameters in sample code is 100cm/s, it is overload the motor.
So what is the true unit of geometry_msgs::Twist or cmd_vel?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/185427/make-sure-geometry_msgs::twist-or-cmd_vel-units/) by [domikilo](https://answers.ros.org/users/8836/domikilo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 89 on 2014-07-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Units are in SI, so the units in the Twist message are, as you say, m/s and rad/s.

You can have a look at [REP 103:Standard Units of Measure and Coordinate Conventions](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html)

---

Originally posted by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) with karma: 843 on 2014-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [domikilo](https://answers.ros.org/users/8836/domikilo/) on 2014-07-08**:
Ok, thanks